# Optimizing modifiable named list based on namedtuple

Tags: python, optimization, csv, namedtuple

My goal is to optimize a framework based on a stack of modifiers for CSV-sourced lists. Each modifier uses a header list to work on a named basis.

CSV example (including header):

```
date;place
13/02/2013;New York
15/04/2012;Buenos Aires
29/10/2010;Singapour
```

I have written some code based on namedtuple in order to be able to use lists generated by csv module without reorganizing data every time. Generated code below :

```
class MyNamedList(object):
        __slots__ = ("__values")
        _fields = ['date', 'ignore', 'place']

        def __init__(self, values):
          self.__values = values
          if len(self.__values) <= 151:
            for i in range(len(self.__values), 151):
              self.__values += [None,]

        @property
        def date(self):
          return self.__values[0]
        @date.setter
        def date(self, val):
          self.__values[0] = val

        @property
        def ignore(self):
          return self.__values[150]
        @ignore.setter
        def ignore(self, val):
          self.__values[150] = val

        @property
        def place(self):
          return self.__values[1]
        @b.setter
        def place(self, val):
          self.__values[1] = val
```

I must say i am very disappointed with performance using this class. Calling a simple modifier function (which changes "ignore" to True 100 times. Yes i know it is useless) for each line of a 70000-line csv file takes 9 seconds (with pypy. 5.5 using original python) whereas equivalent code using a list named foo takes 1.1 second (same with pypy and original python).

Is there anything i could do to get comparable performance between both approaches ? To me, `record.ignore = True` could be directly inlined (or so) and therefore translated into `record[150] = True`. Is there any blocking point i don't see to get this to happen ?

Note that the record i am modifying is actually (for now) not created for each line in the CSV file, meaning adding more items into the list happens only once, before the iteration.

**Update : sample codes**

**--> Using namedlist**

```
import namedlist

MyNamedList=namedlist.namedlist("MyNamedList", {"a":1, "b":2, "ignore":150})
test = MyNamedList([0,1])

def foo(a):
  test.ignore = True # x100 times

import csv
stream = csv.reader(open("66666.csv", "rb"))
for i in stream:
  foo(i)
```

**--> Not using namedlist**

```
import namedlist
import csv

MyNamedList=namedlist.namedlist("MyNamedList", {"a":1, "b":2, "ignore":150})
test = MyNamedList([0,1])

sample_data = []
for i in range(len(sample_data), 151):
  sample_data += [None,]

def foo(a):
  sample_data[150] = True # x100 times

stream = csv.reader(open("66666.csv", "rb"))
for i in stream:
  foo(i)
```

**Update #2 : code for namedlist.py (heavily based on namedtuple.py**

```
# Retrieved from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/500261/
# Licensed under the PSF license

from keyword import iskeyword as _iskeyword
import sys as _sys

def namedlist(typename, field_indices, verbose=False, rename=False):

    # Parse and validate the field names.  Validation serves two purposes,
    # generating informative error messages and preventing template injection attacks.
    field_names = field_indices.keys()
    for name in [typename,] + field_names:
        if not min(c.isalnum() or c=='_' for c in name):
            raise ValueError('Type names and field names can only contain alphanumeric characters and underscores: %r' % name)
        if _iskeyword(name):
            raise ValueError('Type names and field names cannot be a keyword: %r' % name)
        if name[0].isdigit():
            raise ValueError('Type names and field names cannot start with a number: %r' % name)
    seen_names = set()
    for name in field_names:
        if name.startswith('_') and not rename:
            raise ValueError('Field names cannot start with an underscore: %r' % name)
        if name in seen_names:
            raise ValueError('Encountered duplicate field name: %r' % name)
        seen_names.add(name)

    # Create and fill-in the class template
    numfields = len(field_names)
    argtxt = repr(field_names).replace("'", "")[1:-1]   # tuple repr without parens or quotes
    reprtxt = ', '.join('%s=%%r' % name for name in field_names)
    max_index=-1
    for name in field_names:
      index = field_indices[name]
      if max_index < index:
        max_index = index
    max_index += 1
    template = '''class %(typename)s(object):
        __slots__ = ("__values") \n
        _fields = %(field_names)r \n
        def __init__(self, values):
          self.__values = values
          if len(self.__values) <= %(max_index)s:
            for i in range(len(self.__values), %(max_index)s):
              self.__values += [None,]'''% locals()
    for name in field_names:
      index = field_indices[name]
      template += ''' \n
        @property
        def %s(self):
          return self.__values[%d]
        @%s.setter
        def %s(self, val):
          self.__values[%d] = val''' % (name, index, name, name, index)
    if verbose:
        print template

    # Execute the template string in a temporary namespace
    namespace = {'__name__':'namedtuple_%s' % typename,
        '_property':property, '_tuple':tuple}
    try:
        exec template  in namespace
    except SyntaxError, e:
        raise SyntaxError(e.message + ':\n' + template)
    result = namespace[typename]

    # For pickling to work, the __module__ variable needs to be set to the frame
    # where the named tuple is created.  Bypass this step in enviroments where
    # sys._getframe is not defined (Jython for example) or sys._getframe is not
    # defined for arguments greater than 0 (IronPython).
    try:
        result.__module__ = _sys._getframe(1).f_globals.get('__name__', '__main__')
    except (AttributeError, ValueError):
        pass

    return result
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. Please add code that will demonstrate your usage of this class, along with the "equivalent code using a list".

Comment: @perimosocordiae : I have updated my question with testing codes for both cases.

Comment: I don't see how the code of `MyNamedList` is related to the code below: `TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Comment: I am sorry i only provided the generated code and not the generator. I believe it would add useless information to the question. You may replace the generation code by the generated one and you'll be fine.

Comment: I added namedlist.py code in my question.